# how can i send data to server 

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having ASP.NET MVC application in which i have to send data from client browser to the server. 
Client browser means that data is present in javascript function (calculated) 
now what should i use to send this data to server . 
Before MVC, in my old application i was using Web Methods 
Please advice

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

you can use AJAX, e.g. in jQuery:

`$.post(url, { name: "value"}, callback }`

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a controller called HomeController and a actionResult called Index that loads up the index page and another actionResult called SaveData(string data)

Now in the index page you would write your script

```
$(function()
{
   var data = // get data.
   $.post('SaveData',{ sendingData: data}, function(response)
   {
          alert(response);
   });
});

public ActionResult SaveData(string sendingData)
{
   // do somethig with the data  
}
```

Thats all to it. No more making generic handlers or a webserver for each ajax request.