# Passing an array of object in json format from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

```
public Class Object1 {
   int property1
   string property2
   datatime property3
} 

// post method
public virtual void ControllerAction1(Object1[] listOfObjects){

}
```

I am tryign to pass an array of type object1 to the controller method. The client side sends the array in json format. But parameter listOfObjects is null.

Comment: Please include your client code as well so that we may offer a working solution. A common problem is sending an object that has a property that is the array you want rather than just the array.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:

[ASP.NET MVC How to pass JSON object from View to Controller as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter)

You have to use an ObjectFilter to post JSON into an ASP.NET MVC controller action.  This technique *should* allow you to post in an array of JSON-formatted objects.