# pass object to controller via ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have filled object SearchHomeModel and want to pass this object to controller via ajax request. My controller is the following prototype:

```
public ActionResult DataTableUserList(SearchHomeModel search, int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength, string sEcho)
```

and I concat url string for it:

```
    url = "/User/DataTableUserList?SearchHomeModel.FirstName=" + Model.SearchKeys.FirstName + 
        "&SearchHomeModel.LastName=" + Model.SearchKeys.LastName + 
        "&SearchHomeModel.Title=" + Model.SearchKeys.Title + 
        "&SearchHomeModel.Company=" + Model.SearchKeys.Company;
```

(and then pass this url to ajax call)

when I see in debugger call DataTableUserList I see that iDisplayStart has value, but search is null. How to pass this object in my case? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie

Comment: Also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120212/mvc-ajax-json-post-to-controller-action-method

Answer (score 1):

Why not Serialize the form and send to your action method ? If you have binded your model with the form elements, you will get a valid model with values filled there.

```
$.post("/User/DataTableUserList", $("form").serialize(), function (data) {

                     //do what you want with the response from your action method
});
```

Comment: thank you for your variant, but it's not appropriate for my concrete case (i have to pass something more data than form)

Comment: also, page can be without <form>

Comment: Then you can pass items via querystring to the server

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/User/DataTableUserList',
    data: {
        FirstName : '@Model.SearchKeys.FirstName',
        LastName : '@Model.SearchKeys.LastName',
        Title: '@Model.SearchKeys.Title',
        Company: '@Model.SearchKeys.Company'
    },
    success: function(result){
        // Do Something with Result
    }
});
```

Hopefully the MVC Model Binder will do the work for you this way.

Comment: why it could be inside search object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this instead:

```
url = "/User/DataTableUserList?search.FirstName=" + Model.SearchKeys.FirstName + 
        "&search.LastName=" + Model.SearchKeys.LastName + 
        "&search.Title=" + Model.SearchKeys.Title + 
        "&search.Company=" + Model.SearchKeys.Company;
```

I hope this helps :-)