# How to post model to a controller in Smart Wizard?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, model

All I wanted to do is do an **$.ajax()** post back when a user goes from step 2 to step 3 in smart wizard. So i worked out the following code. I have used **var model = JSON.stringify(@Model);** to convert my model to string and pass it using ajax request

**Ajax code**

```
 var model = JSON.stringify(@Model);
                var s = 10;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSampleFeed")',
                    data: "inStringModel=" + model
                });
```

but the above does not fire an call back to the controller. I have checked by removing the JSON.stringify(@Model) and replaced it by "Just text". Now the ajax request reaches the controller with out any issues

Below are my codes

**Model File**

```
public class OndemandFeedModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of countrt that the application supports
    /// </summary>
    public CountryModel Country { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Model used to display fields and retrive the selected fields from user
    /// </summary>
    public FieldSelectModel Fields { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Model used to display filters and retrive the selected fields from user
    /// </summary>
    public FilterSelectModel Filters { get; set; }
}

public class FieldSelectModel
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of Fields
    /// </summary>
    public List<FieldGroup> FieldGroup { get; set; }
}

public class FilterSelectModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="From")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="To")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public FilterSelectModel()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class FieldGroup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// group of the field
    /// </summary>
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// group of the field
    /// </summary>
    public List<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique Id referred to each field
    /// </summary>
    public int FieldId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// name of the field
    /// </summary>
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// user defined name for the field
    /// </summary>
    public string UserDefinedFieldName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// bool value indicating whether the field has been selected by the user
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsEdited { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// type of the field coded / raw
    /// </summary>
    public string FieldType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// category of the field in which it has been clasified
    /// </summary>
    public string FieldGroup { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// status of the field if status is 1 display field to user other wise dont display
    /// </summary>
    public int Status { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// country of field
    /// </summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Title attribute for the element will be poped up in tool tip
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public FieldModel()
    {
        IsEdited = false;
        UserDefinedFieldName = string.Empty;
        Title = "Double click each fields to edit.";
    }
}
```

My View

**My Javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard({
            onShowStep: showAStepCallback,
            onFinish: onFinishCallback
        });

        function showAStepCallback(obj, context) {

            if (context.fromStep == 2 && context.toStep == 3) {
                var model = JSON.stringify(@Model);
                var s = 10;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSampleFeed")',
                    data: "inStringModel=" + model
                });

            }

            // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation 
        }
        // setting the active tab
        $('#wizard').smartWizard();
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        function onFinishCallback() {
            $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage', 'Finish Clicked');
            //alert('Finish Clicked');
        }
            .....
    });
</script>
```

**Controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSampleFeed(string inStringModel)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var inObjectModel = serializer.Deserialize(inStringModel, typeof(OndemandFeedModel));
    return Content("<row></row>");
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated !!

Thanks

**Update 1**

I have changed the

```
var model = JSON.stringify(@Model);
```

to

```
var model = @{new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}
```

now the request reaches controller but the model i received is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(@Model);` isn't going to do what you think it's going to do. `JSON.stringify` expects a Javascript object. `@Model` is going to have Razor output the contents of `Model.ToString();`, which will not be a Javascript object.

You need to serialize your model to Javascript, which you can do using the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var model = @{new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)};
                var s = 10;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSampleFeed")',
                    data: model
                });
```

You can find the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in the System.Web.Extensions DLL.

Also, since you are deserializing your model, you do not need to convert it to/from JSON. MVC and jQuery will handle this for you, so on your controller side you can do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSampleFeed(OndemandFeedModel model)
{
    return Content(string.Format("<row>{0}</row>", model.RowName));
}
```

Comment: Hi Blade, Thanks for the reply. I have tried as you have suggested now the request reaches controller but i have received an empty model.

Comment: @Umamaheswaran Use either Chrome console/Firefox Firebug to check exactly what data is sent to the server. You may need to change some parameters to make sure MVC recognises it as JSON. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120212/mvc-ajax-json-post-to-controller-action-method