# TempData in Asp.net MVC is not working exactly the same as session in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `TempData[]` in MVC application but its not working fine as like that session.

After refresh the page after login page then tempdata have null value please suggest me and
also using in `web.config`

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10"/>.
```

Comment: Please, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc/1500485#1500485

Comment: If you need something like session, why don't you just use session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData is available only for a user’s session, so it persists only till we have read it and gets cleared at the end of an HTTP Request. A scenario that fits the usage of TempData, is when data needs to persist between two requests – a redirect scenario. You can use method Keep to store until next request

```
   TempData.Keep
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703497.aspx

To fill data from controller, create action:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
   // get data from your data source, replace with db call or where to get data
   var data = new [] {"sample1", "sample2"};

   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

on client when you need data:

```
$.getJSON(@Url.Action("GetData"), function(data) {
   // fill dropdown instead alert
   alert(data);
});
```

See more:

[AJAX request aspnet](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/how-make-ajax-requests-aspnet)

[similar question but for post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120212/mvc-ajax-json-post-to-controller-action-method)

Comment: Thanks Syned, its working fine. But I have one more question related to session value. how to manage the session into generic handler class?

Comment: What do you mean "into generic handler class"? Describe please your use case.

Comment: Genric handler for http web request which is inherit the "IHttpHandler" interface.

Comment: Most of time you don't need handlers in your mvc application, why do you need it?

Comment: Genric handler use for fill drop down using jquery.

Comment: If data is related to some controller just add method to that controller and use ajax to get it

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be null after a refresh because TempData is meant only for a single redirect. In your case you must use Session instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right after refresh the page or single redirect TempData loose the data. But I thing session is not good way in MVC application

Comment: TempData uses session.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in session.

for example

```
 public static int Points
        {
            get
            {
                int points = Convert.ToInt32( HttpContext.Current.Session["PointssessionKey"]); 
                return  points;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["PointssessionKey"] = value;
            }
        }
```

and also keep in temp data as

**TempData.Keep**