# MVC ajax post to controller action method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been looking at the question here: [MVC ajax json post to controller action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120212/mvc-ajax-json-post-to-controller-action-method) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be helping me. Mine is pretty much the exact same, except my method signature (but I've tried that and it still doesn't get hit).

### jQuery

```
$('#loginBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // TODO: Validate input

    var data = {
        username: $('#username').val().trim(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50061/checkin/app/login",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(d) {
            if (d.success == true)
                window.location = "index.html";
            else {}
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // TODO: Show error
        }
    });
});
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    string error = "";
    if (!WebSecurity.IsAccountLockedOut(username, 3, 60 * 60))
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(username, password))
            return Json("'Success':'true'");
        error = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
    }
    else
        error = "Too many failed login attempts. Please try again later.";

    return Json(String.Format("'Success':'false','Error':'{0}'", error));
}
```

However, no matter what I try, my `Controller` never gets hit. Through debugging, I know that it sends a request, it just gets a `Not Found` error each time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your Action is expecting string parameters, but you're sending a composite object.

You need to create an object that matches what you're sending.

```
public class Data
{
    public string username { get;set; }
    public string password { get;set; }
}

public JsonResult Login(Data data)
{
}
```

**EDIT**

In addition, toStringify() is probably not what you want here. Just send the object itself.

```
data: data,
```

Answer (score 4):

It's due to you sending one object, and you're expecting two parameters.

Try this and you'll see:

```
public class UserDetails
{
   public string username { get; set; }
   public string password { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Login(UserDetails data)
{
   string error = "";
   //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: http://localhost:50061/checkin/app/login - is it WebAPI you're calling? Should this 'app' be 'api'? And is this in a Controller? If so it should be something like http://localhost:50061/checkin/app/Controller/login

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
/////// Controller post and get simple text value 
[HttpPost]
    public string Contact(string message)
    { 
        return "<h1>Hi,</h1>we got your message, <br />" + message + " <br />Thanks a lot";
    }
```

//// in the view add reference to the Javascript (jQuery) files

```
@section Scripts{

<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
}
```

/// then add the Post method as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

/// post and get text value
    
$("#send").on("click", function () {    
$.post('', { message: $('#msg').val() })  

//// empty post('') means post to the default controller, 
///we are not pacifying different action or controller
/// however we can define a url as following:
/// var url = "@(Url.Action("GetDataAction", "GetDataController"))"

         .done(function (response) {
             $("#myform").html(response);
        })
        .error(function () { alert('Error') })
        .success(function () { alert('OK') })
        return false;
    });
```

---

Now let's say you want to do it using $.Ajax and JSON:

```
// Post JSON data  add using System.Net;
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult JsonFullName(string fname, string lastname)
    {
        var data = "{ \"fname\" : \"" + fname  + " \" , \"lastname\" : \"" + lastname + "\" }";
//// you have to add the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
 //// otherwise it will throw an exception on run-time.
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }
```

Then, inside your view: add the event click on a an input of type button, or even a from submit:
Just make sure your JSON data is well formatted.

```
  $("#jsonGetfullname").on("click", function () { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "@(Url.Action("JsonFullName", "Home"))",
            data: "{ \"fname\" : \"Mahmoud\" , \"lastname\" : \"Sayed\" }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#myform").html("<h3>Json data: <h3>" + res.fname + ", " + res.lastname)
            }, 
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            } 
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way of using ajax which helped me as it was better in use as not having complex json syntaxes

```
//fifth
function GetAjaxDataPromise(url, postData) {
    debugger;
    var promise = $.post(url, postData, function (promise, status) {
    });
    return promise;
};
$(function () {
    $("#btnGet5").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var promises = GetAjaxDataPromise('@Url.Action("AjaxMethod", "Home")', { EmpId: $("#txtId").val(), EmpName: $("#txtName").val(), EmpSalary: $("#txtSalary").val() });
        promises.done(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert("Hello: " + response.EmpName + " Your Employee Id Is: " + response.EmpId + "And Your Salary Is: " + response.EmpSalary);
        });
    });
});
```

This method comes with jquery promise the best part was on controller we can received data by using separate parameters or just by using a model class.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(PersonModel personModel)
    {
        PersonModel person = new PersonModel
        {
            EmpId = personModel.EmpId,
            EmpName = personModel.EmpName,
            EmpSalary = personModel.EmpSalary
        };
        return Json(person);
    }
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string empId, string empName, string empSalary)
    {
        PersonModel person = new PersonModel
        {
            EmpId = empId,
            EmpName = empName,
            EmpSalary = empSalary
        };
        return Json(person);
    }
```

It works for both of the cases. SO you must try out this way.

Answer (score -4):

```
$('#loginBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /// it should not have this code or else it wont continue
    //....
});
```

Comment: This is simply incorrect. `e.preventDefault()` does not halt execution of the click handler. It prevents the *default* actions from occurring, such as submission of a form, navigation to another page, etc.