# JsonResult controller parameter always null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using extremely similar code on another view and controller that is working perfectly but for some reason I cannot get this one to work. No matter what I do the controller parameters show undefined even though name and pass in the javascript are working correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
View:

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <fieldset>
 <legend>User</legend>
       Username:
            @Html.TextBox("txtUsername")
       <br/>
       Password:
            @Html.TextBox("txtPassword")
       <br />
       <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="Login" />
       </p>
 </fieldset>
 }       

 <script>

 $(function() {
      $("#btnLogin").click(login);
 });

     function login() {
         var name = $('#txtUsername').val();
         var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();

     $.post("/User/Login/" + name + "/" + pass, null, loginSuccess, "json");
}

function loginSuccess(result) {
    alert(result);
}

</script>


Controller:

public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View("Login");
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(string name, string pass)
{
    string result = "test result";

    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Will you post your controller action method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need is:

```
View:

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <fieldset>
 <legend>User</legend>
   Username:
        @Html.TextBox("txtUsername")
   <br/>
   Password:
        @Html.TextBox("txtPassword")
   <br />
   <p>
        <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login" />
   </p>
 </fieldset>
 }
```

Then the controller:

```
Controller:

public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View("Login");
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(string name, string pass)
{
    string result = "test result";

    return Json(result);
}
```

The ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#btnLogin" ).click(function() {


$.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("YourControllerActionName", "YourControllerName")",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    name: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    pass: $('#txtPassword').val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
                      alert(result); 
                }
            });
});
<script>
```

Comment: This is not true if the OP really needs things done asynchronously and  without a page reload. You're better off asking the OP (in a comment) why a particular approach is being used. With this approach the callback function `loginSuccess` will never be called.

Comment: yea, probably I should add another ajax method. Editted answer.

Comment: Using your exact ajax code I still get null. I obviously added the controller names etc. without the ajax it works but yes i would like it to be a ajax/json call. Im completely baffled

Comment: try change the button input type to **type="button"**

Comment: That was it! Thank You. Please edit your answer to include and I will mark yours

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do it the way you have it, but I would need to see your routes as well.  There is a better way to make this call though.

```
var data = {
    "name": $('#txtUsername').val(),
    "pass": $('#txtPassword').val()
};

$.post('@Url.Action("Login", "Home")', data, function(response) {
   //Do something with the response if you like
});
```

Comment: Is the var pass a mistype on the 3rd line?

Comment: Also getting a syntax error on the comma after the controller name

Comment: Yes, sorry for the copy paste error.  The @UrlAction also needs to be surrounded in quotes which I initially omitted.  I have made the updates.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like string concatenation and hard-coded strings.

First, let's use an HTML helper to resolve an action's URL.

```
@Url.Action("Login", "User")
```

Second, let's pass the data as a javascript object.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Login", "User")",
    {
        name: name,
        pass: pass
    }, loginSuccess, "application/json");
```

Comment: Looks good but I am getting a syntax error on this comma "User"),

Comment: It would just be the HTML parser complaining because, according to it, there is nothing in between the `(` and the `,` since it ignores the Razor syntax. It's pretty standard. You can ignore it or simply change it to `$.post("@Url.Action("Login", "User")",`.

Comment: Gotcha, still getting null on the parameters in the json result.

Comment: No go...   $(function() {
        $("#btnLogin").click(login);
    });

    function login() {
        var name = $('#txtUsername').val();
        var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();

        $.post(@Url.Action("Login", "User"),
        {
            name: name,
            pass: pass
        }, loginSuccess, "application/json");
    }
    
    function loginSuccess()
    {
        
    };

Comment: No matter what I do username and password are still null

Comment: Make sure you add the quotes around Url.Action (updated my sample). Also, are you clicking the login button (and not pressing the enter key)?

Comment: I'm guessing it was the quotes in front of "@Url that i was missing. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

you are sending parameters as a part of the URL (thus, effectively, making it GET regardless of jquery $.post() ) and your controller strictly expects HttpPost (meaning, parameters in http request body, not in query string).

leaving aside that fact that having username/password in url is extremely bad practice.

try sending data as:

$.post('url/of/the/controller', {name: $('#txtUsername').val(), pass: $('#txtPassword').val()});

Answer (score 1):

You are making the call your controller action method incorrectly. Try passing `name` and `pass` as data in the `$.post` call instead of appended on to the url.

It also may be cleaner to make your controller action method take a model of type `LogIn`. `LogIn` could have two properties (`Name` and `Pass`). That way when you send data in `$.post`
you can send it like `{ name: 'someName', pass: 'somePass' }`.

Comment: "You are making the call your controller action method incorrectly. Try passing name and pass as data in the $.post call instead of appended on to the url."   Thank you! Can you show an example?

Comment: @osiris355 what? Edit: Okay look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19663938/1165441

So your post would be `$.post("/User/Login/", { name: "someName", pass: "somePass" } );`

Comment: I am new to mvc and json. Can you show how I would pass the data? I have only done it in the url which was working in my other views for some reason

Comment: @osiris355 I edited my comment. POST requests work different than GET in that you send data directly after the HTTP headers that your browser sends to the server. More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876931/1165441

Comment: Still getting null in controller $(function() {
        $("#btnLogin").click(login);
    });

    function login() {
        var name = $('#txtUsername').val();
        var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();

        $.post(@Url.Action("Login", "User"),
        {
            name: name,
            pass: pass
        }, loginSuccess, "application/json");
    }
    
    function loginSuccess()
    {
        
    };

Comment: Please don't mix Razor and JavaScript. Take a look at the links in previous comments. There are other questions similar to this.

Comment: I did and no matter what I do it is always null. I think something else is going on

Answer (score 1):

You can Post it as ::

```
    $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:"User/Login",
           data:{UserName:$("#UserName").val(),Password:$("#Password").val()},
           success:function(data){
               alert(data);
           }
    })
```

and On Server side you will get the Information like::

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(string Username, string Password)
{
    string result = "test result";

    return Json(result);
}
```