# How to send client data to MVC controller for Login page?And save to database?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

Login.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function data() {
    var n = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var m = document.getElementById("password").value;
    ?
</script>

<button  type="submit"class="btn-login" onClick="Data()">
                        Giriş Yap </button>
```

Account Controller

```
  DBEntities dB = new DBEntities();
  [HttpPost]                         (username)       (password)
    public ActionResult Login(string KullaniciAdi,string Sifre)
    {
      //  Session[KullaniciAdi] = dB.Profil.Where(x => x.KullaniciAdi == KullaniciAdi && x.Sifre == Sifre).FirstOrDefault();
        var session = (from p in dB.Profil
                       where p.KullaniciAdi == KullaniciAdi
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(); 
    }
```

My OOP homework is this website and i want to create a login with sending password and username to controller and compare submitted data and the data in the database .Please help :)

Comment: Please visit this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-mvc-using-entity-framework-with-ajax-call-jquery-and-all-val/

Comment: You can use Ajax:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663762/mvc-ajax-post-to-controller-action-method?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: what's wrong with using a regular form submission? Or are you trying to do it without a page refresh (i.e. ajax)? It's not clear.

Comment: I can't submit  username and password to action in controller .It is not  relevant with refreshing

Comment: ".It is not relevant with refreshing" I have no idea what this means. Can you clarify? What's wrong with using a form to do this (as per the answer below)?

Comment: I really tried to understand you .thank you for your attention.I will look to the answer it looks helpful but i was looking an answer my javascript code for sending and for account controller .I am new at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send client data by using ajax request,

this is your inputs

```
<input id="username" type="text" />
<input id="password" type="password" /> 
<input id="loginbutton" onclick="UserLogin()" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Submit button bind with *UserLogin* js function.

here is the js function. we are sending ajax post request here to our controller

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function UserLogin() {
        var n = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var p = document.getElementById("password").value;

        var postObj = JSON.stringify({
            "username": n,
            "password": p
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Login", // endpoint
            type: "POST",
            data: postObj,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                // success
            },
            error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And your controller should be like, you can implement login logic inside of the method.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
  {
      // use your code loged in

      return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

First You Create a Class :

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name can not be empty!")]
        public string LOGINID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password can not be empty!")]
        public string LOGINPW { get; set; }      

    }
```

Then Your Controller Action Method do this:

```
     public ActionResult Login()
     {           
         return View();    
     }

    [HttpPost]                         
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {

       //Here check the Login Id and Password 
        return View(); 

    }
```

Now in view Write this. Now when you click the submit button a post call go to the Login Controller with given LOGINID and LOGINPW :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

         <!-- login screen -->  

                <form action="#">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LOGINID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Login ID" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LOGINID, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "float: left" })

                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LOGINPW, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LOGINPW, "", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "float: left" })


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: #2e6da4; color: #FFF;">Login</button>

                </form>              

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{
        var actionURL = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", 
                                   FormMethod.Post, Request.Url.Scheme)  
                        + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                                       new { @action = actionURL }))
    {
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password">
<button  type="submit"class="btn-login"></button>
    }//Then use Request.Form[0] with the id to get the user name and password in the controller action.
```