# How to bind FromRoute to QueryObject in .net core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have this query object:

```
public class GetRecipeQuery: IRequest<RecipeResponse>
{
    [BindRequired]
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RecipeController
{
    private AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;   

    public RecipeController(AppDbContext context, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }
    
    [HttpGet("{Id}")]
    // http://localhost:5555/Recipe/555
    public RecipeResponse Get([FromRoute]GetRecipeQuery query)
    {
        if (query.Id == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No Id!", nameof(query.Id));
        }
        var result = _mediator.Send(query).Result;
        return result;
    } 
}
```

So I see this as a result:

```
Status: 400
"The value '{Id}' is not valid for Id."
```

Need help: How to bind `Id` from route to `GetRecipeQuery.Id` ?
Otherwise i need to construct query objects manually in every controller method.

Comment: Hello @nvff and welcome to Stackoverflow. I think you need to specify the type `[HttpGet("{Id:int}")]`?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641426/passing-objects-as-url-parameters-c-sharp

Comment: I test your code, it works correctly, but what is the `RecipeResponse`?

Comment: @Karney, RecipeResponse is return data class. {id, err}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@tontonsevilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8795884/tontonsevilla), answered my question. Thanks.

`[HttpGet("{Id:int}")]` returns 404 error, but `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]` works fine! Need lowercase and type for `Id` parameter.

Full solution.

1). Add query class

```
public class GetRecipeQuery : IRequest<RecipeResponse>
{
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

2). Use this query class in Controller and add `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`:

```
 [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
 public RecipeResponse Get(GetRecipeQuery query)
 {
    // your code
 }
```

I need it because I started using [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you confuse a bit route parameters and query parameters. If you want to use URL parameters your endpoint in controller should be a value type:

```
[FromRoute]int id
```

Then URL you are calling would approximately look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/10
```

If you want to use query parameters this is how your controller endpoint argument would look like:

```
[FromQuery]Foo query
```

With Foo looking like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And the address you need to call:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo?id=10
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we can use [FromQuery] and that is simple. But I wanted to bind from route. And, it turns out, there is a solution