# Send List<class> from js to controller using $.redirectPost() MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

As the title say, I need to send from a .js file some values to a MVC controller, one of that values is an object array that corresponds to an List<> in the controller, the problem is that when arrives to the controller the List count is 0, this is my code:

In the .js:

```
var listaParametros = [
               { "Identificador": "1", "Tipo": "MG", "Texto": "Escala de calificación", "Valor": "/EscalaCalificacion/Listado", "IdRetorno": identificadorRetorno, "RecuerdaFiltros": recuerdaFiltros }
    ];

    var maestroEscalaCalificacionE =
        {
            IdentificadorMaestroEscalaCalificacion: $('#grid-tableEscalaCalificacion').jqGrid('getRowData', elementoSeleccionado).IdentificadorMaestroEscalaCalificacion,
            IndicadorActivo: $('#ddlIndicadorActivo').val(),
            ListaParametros: listaParametros
        };

    $.redirectPost(window.rootUrl + "/EscalaCalificacion/Consultar", maestroEscalaCalificacionE);
```

The ActionResult on the Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Consultar(EscalaCalificacionMaestroE maestroEscalaCalificacionE)
```

The List is a public property of the class EscalaCalificacionMaestroE.

By the way, I'm using $.redirectPost() because I need to go to another page when the ActionResult finishes.

[UPDATE]
This is the function redirectPost()

```
redirectPost: function (location, args) {
            var form = '';

            var jForm = $('<form></form>', {
                action: location,
                method: 'post'
            });

            $.each(args, function (key, value) {
                $("<input>", {
                    name: key,
                    value: value,
                    type: 'hidden'
                }).appendTo(jForm);
            });

            jForm.appendTo('body').submit();
        }
```

Now, when I use $.ajax, all works like a charm, but don't know how to get the new page, any help on getting to the new page?

Comment: What does `$.redirectPost` do ? never heard of it. Also you cannot (and should not try to ) pass a complex object via query string. You should do a form post.

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: Well, if you already have an `$.ajax()` call that works, then all you have to do is calling `window.location.assign()` in your success function. Otherwise, if you want to do it by submitting a form, then just return a view in your action method and page will refresh.

Comment: Creating `input` elements won't work for `List` properties. Instead of that, [make an ajax post call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327046/3082296) and redirect to a new page in the ajax `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, your ideas help me to solve it, the architecture of the project, there are certain things that I can not use, but mixing ideas I solved it in the following way (I am aware that it is not the best in terms of security practices, but I can not change it):

I made a function similar to redirectPost () called "Redirection", but it would allow me to create an HTML input for each value in the list with the following format:

key: List [0] [PropertyName]

value: parameterValue

Then when the submit executes, the "List" on the controller has the right values.

Once again thanks everyone!

BTW, this is the code, maybe someone can need it!

```
function Redirection(location, args) {
    var form = '';
    var jForm = $('<form></form>', {
        action: location,
        method: 'post'
    });
    iterateValues(args, [], jForm, null, false)
    jForm.appendTo('body').submit();
}

function getInput(name, value, parent, isArray, isTraditionalArray) {
    var parentString;
    if (parent.length > 0) {
        parentString = parent[0];
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < parent.length; i += 1) {
            parentString += "[" + parent[i] + "]";
        }
        if (isArray) {
            if (isTraditionalArray)
                name = parentString;
            else
                name = parentString + "[" + name + "]";
        } else {
            name = parentString + "[" + name + "]";
        }
    }
    return $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden")
        .attr("name", name)
        .attr("value", value);
};
function iterateValues(values, parent, form, isArray,  isTraditionalArray) {
    var i, iterateParent = [];
     Object.keys(values).forEach(function (i) {
        if (typeof values[i] === "object") {
            iterateParent = parent.slice();
            iterateParent.push(i);
            iterateValues(values[i], iterateParent, form, Array.isArray(values[i]), isTraditionalArray);
        } else {
             form.append(getInput(i, values[i], parent, isArray, isTraditionalArray));
        }
    });
};
```