# Working with identifiers as arrays and sending to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have some identifiers on my page. Named id[0], id[1] all the way to id[20] and sometimes more. I need to send these to an MVC controller and I would like to package them up as one object and unpack at the controller. Can someone tell me if this is possible, my knowledge of javascript is just basic so I'd really appreciate advice on which way to go. For example can I use JSON or serialize. btw I'm using jQuery.

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data in JSON.

See  > [ASP.NET MVC How to pass JSON object from View to Controller as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter)

Comment: Yeah but how do I wrap it up? I want to try and do it by looping as all my id's have names that have an index number such as id[index]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `id` array (id[0], id[1](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) , ... id[20]) you can convert it to JSON string with respect of `JSON.stringify(id)` where `JSON.stringify` function defined in the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

On the server side you can use for example [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx) method of the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to convert the data to `List<T>` where `T` is type of `id[i]` (for example `string`).

How to send data with respect of `jQuery.ajax` you already know from another answer.