# Sending Data From javaScript Which Is retrived from LocalStorage(WebSql) and pass to MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, web-sql

```
        db.transaction(
           function (transaction) {
               transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO EmployeeTable(Firstname,Lastname,BirthDate,EmployeeType,MaritalStatus,Company,IsActive,Dependents) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                   [Firstname.toString(), Lastname.toString(), BirthDate, parseInt(empType), parseInt(marital),Company.toString(),active, parseInt(Dependents)]);

               transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable', [], function (transaction, results) {

                   result = results;

                   alert(result.length);

                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                        var EmployeeID = results.rows.item(i).EmployeeID;
                        var Firstname = results.rows.item(i).Firstname;
                        var Lastname = results.rows.item(i).Lastname;

                        alert(results.rows.item(i).EmployeeID + "  " + results.rows.item(i).Firstname + "  " + results.rows.item(i).Lastname);
                        //var product =  [productid, productname, price, qty];                     
                        //insertTableRow(product,i);
                    }




                  }, null);    
           }
         );
```

am Using WEB SQL as Local  Database

want to send data retrived  from websql using
db.Transaction() method
to server controller.

Please Help On same.....

How should i transfer data to controller of mvc.....

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Save(0, collection))
            {
                // List<char> bulkdata = collection["bulkdata"].ToList();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            else
            {
                return View("Edit");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [tutorial](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-synchronized-online-offline-data-application-with-javascript-and-jaydata) shows an example how to sync local db with a WCF Data Service endpoint. By combining this with the [WebAPI tutorial](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-use-jaydata-with-asp.net-web-api---i) you will be able to sync to the online DB with these lines:

```
function synchronizeData() {
        offlinedb
            .TodoItems
            .filter("it.InSync === false")
            .toArray(function (todoItems) {
                onlinedb.addMany(todoItems);
                onlinedb.saveChanges(function () {
                    todoItems.forEach(function (todoItem) {
                        offlinedb.attach(todoItem);
                        todoItem.InSync = true;
                    });
                    offlinedb.saveChanges(function () {
                        listLocalTodoItems();
                        listRemoteTodoItems();
                    });
                });
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try serializing your localstorage string and then send to the server...

[ASP.NET MVC How to pass JSON object from View to Controller as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter)