# Encode or hide request payload in ASP.NET MVC4 POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 web application, I have to support (which I did not write).

When I upload a text file and submit, then check the "Network" tab in Chrome I see "Request Payload" as:

```
{"filePath":"C:\\TempFiles\\MyData.txt","fileName":"MyData.txt"}
```

I don't want to see "Request Payload" in raw JSON format, want it in encoded format.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide information about  `Content-Type` header of your `POST` request

Comment: Sounds like the view is using AJAX to submit. Just use a normal form.

Comment: @Urahara, The content type is: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Have seen this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter go over it.

Comment: @Urahara, I gone through the link, but not gives my questions answer.

Comment: JSON sent`POST` with correct header is parsed as `string` to be revived with `JSON.parse()` to the original JSON format.

Comment: Wait, is this an MVC question or just a Chrome question? Encoded how?

Comment: @Visser, This is an MVC question.

Comment: @MarsRoverII It's still unclear what you're asking. You see a JSON string  in Chome when you hit submit. What do you want to see and where do you want to see it? "Encoded format" isn't specific at all. What would you want to see in your MyData.txt example?