# Is it acceptable to return <anonymous> from an asmx service method

Tags: ajax, asmx

[This comment to an answer from John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301802/examples-of-practical-usage-of-json-to-and-from-an-asmx-web-service-via-jquery/1301837#1301837), a very high-rep member of Stack Overflow, says that returning an anonymous type from a web service is a bad practice.

Assuming I have the luxury of not caring about graceful degradation of my website in the face of users with Javascript disabled, why is it bad practice to have a service method, that exists only to be called via Ajax, return an anonymous object?

It seems like such a waste to whip up a concrete type, whose sole purpose is to hold my data for a few microseconds before asp.net serializes it into JSON.

Comment: Found this questions while trying to figure out why my ASMX tries to use XML serialization even if I forced JSON both on the ScriptMethod attribute and in the ajax call, and thus it won't serialize my anonymous object because it does not have a parameterless constructor. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @MatteoMosca - that should work.  There's probably a problem in your code - just post a new question and I'm sure someone can help.  But yeah, returning <anonymous> should *work* fine, and be serialized into json without a problem - this question was about best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was specific to SOAP web services. Consumers of SOAP web services are accustomed to working with strongly-typed data, so returning an object of anonymous type via an `object` return type will force them to parse the XML, which they aren't accustomed to doing.

However, for clients which do not expect (or understand) strongly-typed data, my comment does not apply. If they are already accustomed to parsing XML, or `eval`ing JSON, then returning an anonymous object won't make that worse.