# jQuery submit a form and its model to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to submit a form using jQuery and submit it to a controller action for processing, to include all the model properties, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to pass your own complex model directly into the controller method from jQuery, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267707/how-to-pass-complex-type-using-json-to-asp-net-mvc-controller).

Answer (score 4):

Create your Controller Action with the FormCollection declared. Then just call UpdateModel which will map your forms properties to your object.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
{
    MyDomainObject a = //possibly get from repository

    try
    {
        UpdateModel(a);
        ...
```

Your View

```
<form id='my-form' action='post' method='/MyController/MyAction'>
    //form elements
</form>
```

And here's some javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var f = $('my-form');
    var action = f.attr('action');
    var serializedForm = f.serialize();
    $.post
    (
        action,
        serializedForm,
        function()
        {
            //anything after the form submit
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `FormCollection` with this - this can also be an MVC model or viewmodel, though I used `.serializeArray()` instead of `.serialize()` when I did this.  Also used `$.post(method, serializedForm, function() {} );` instead of `action, serializedForm` shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to send additional informational along with the information in the form?

If so, I would just dynamically create `<input type="hidden">` elements and append them to the form before submitting.