# Flattening a complex json object for mvc binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

My controller is returning an object graph to the view in json format like this

```
return Json(customer);
```

On the view my json object looks like this

```
{
    Name: 'Joe',
    Budget: { Amount: 500, Spend: 100 }
}
```

Which maps correctly to my customer object:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Budget Budget{get;set;} 
}

public class Budget  
{
    public decimal Amount{get;set;}    
    public decimal Spend{get;set;} 
}
```

I want to pass that same json object back to another method on the controller with this signature:

```
public ActionResult Method(Customer customer)
```

When I do this customer's name get populated but not the Budget class, which I understand why because the modelbinder is expecting this: {Name:'Joe','Budget.Amount':500,'Budget.Spend': 100}

So I have to options:
1. I can return the json object in the format it wants, but I don't know how because you can't do this:

```
return Json(new { Budget.Amount= 500})
```

2. I can flatten the json object on the client side. Is there plugins or methods to do this?

Comment: but you can do this, right?  not sure if this solves your entire problem:  
return Json(new { Budget = new { Amount = 500 }})

Comment: i am trying to flatten json object so that the result is '{ 'Budget.Amount' = 500 }'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that convert an object to a flat hash

```
function flatten(json){
    var nj = {},
        walk = function(j){
            var jp;
            for(var prop in j){
                jp = j[prop];
                if(jp.toString() === "[object Object]"){
                    walk(jp);
                }else{
                    nj[prop] = jp;
                }
            }
        };
    walk(json);
    return nj;
}
```

Comment: Oh no... you want to flatten the json into a hash?

Comment: your solution will work, but I will need to have 'Budget.Amount' as the property name, I am currently doing it by passing a prefix variable to the 'walk' function

Comment: About the bad practice... I don't know your constraints server side, but yeah... it looks like a receipt for troubles.

Answer (score 1):

[Protovis has a JavaScript flattener](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/jsdoc/symbols/pv.Flatten.html), [available](https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/blob/master/protovis.js#L2485) under the [BSD License](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case we have solved it by passing additional object to the action url.

public ActionResult Method(Customer customer, [Bind(Prefix="Budget")]Budget budget)

to make this happen you have to flatten the json data (before you sent it to controller) in following way:

[How to pass complex type using json to ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267707/how-to-pass-complex-type-using-json-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)