# ASP.NET MVC 2 How to pass JSON to ASP.NET Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Wondering if there is a better way to do this with ASP.NET MVC2. The following Posts on SO are little dated:

[How to pass complex type using json to ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267707/how-to-pass-complex-type-using-json-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)

[ASP.NET MVC How to pass JSON object from View to Controller as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560575/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-json-object-from-view-to-controller-as-parameter)

and also without using phil haack's futures library in the following post.
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Basically what I am doing right now is using the JavaScriptSerializer and deserializing in action/actionfilter.

Comment: This is very actual for me, either!

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack's post is still up to date for MVC 2 - you need to register a `JsonValueProviderFactory` to deserialize an object from the posted JSON.

This is baked into MVC 3 already, so I would suggest downloading the MVC 3 preview and taking the `JsonValueProviderFactory` from the assembly

Comment: I can't use MVC 3 preview for a production App. Also using MVC futures is not an option :(

Comment: I'm not suggesting using MVC3 in your app, just the JsonValueProviderFactory class from the assembly. or you could write your own instead :)