# Backbone save, model data not recieved on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post, backbone.js, controller

I'm using backbone with ASP.NET MVC. I want to save a model to the server.

#### Folder model

```
Folder = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({   
url: "/SaveFolder",

relations: [
    {
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'Files', /*key should match the JSON name*/           
        relatedModel: 'FileModel',
        collectionType: 'FileCollection',            
    }
],
idAttribute: "FolderID"
```

});

#### Folder saving code in the view

```
 var newFolder = new Folder();
    newFolder.set("FolderName", newFolderName);
    newFolder.set("EditableByOthers", "N");
    newFolder.save({
        success: function(model, response, options) {
            alert("success"); //not reached
        },
        error: function (model, xhr, options) {
            alert("error"); //not reached
        }
    });
```

#### Note: The success and error alerts never fire.

#### When I check in Fiddler, the JSON being sent is -

```
{"Files":[],"FolderName":"new","EditableByOthers":"Y"}
```

#### My controller on the serverside, however, recieves an empty Folder object -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveFolder(Folder newFolder) //All properties of newFolder are null, or "N" in case of boolean
    {
        string name = newFolder.FolderName;
        return null;
    }
```

#### Folder class on the server -

```
public class Folder
{
    public int? FolderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId;        
    public string FolderName;
    public bool EditableByOthers;
    public IList<File> Files;
}
```

I can't really point at what's fishy here. But again, I'm a backbone newbie, so I could easily have missed something. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: If you are confirming it is being sent via ajax, then this problem seems like it is server side, not client side - no ?

Comment: Yes, it does seem so. But my models on both ends do match, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Does the JSON seem right to you? Is it expected to be something like {"Folder": {"Files":[],"FolderName":"new","EditableByOthers":"Y"}} ?

Comment: Also neither the success nor error callbacks are being reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was having public fields on the model instead of properties. Simple issue, not so simple to locate. This post helped me - [How to pass complex type using json to ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267707/how-to-pass-complex-type-using-json-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)